# Dealing with large slowdown when moving PyTorch code to GPU

Tags: python, neural-network, gpu, pytorch

I have a Graph Neural Network model I have written using Pytorch. On my CPU I am not getting fantastic performance, so I tried to port it over to a V100 GPU I have access to. In this process, I have received a huge performance decrease (around 10times slower).

I have two ideas of where might be the issue, but I would like some input to try get the optimum performance from my model. The first problem might be coming from my custom graph convolutional layer:

```
class GraphConvLayer(torch.nn.Module):
    """
    Based, basically, on https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02907
    Have some modifications:
    https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-do-deep-learning-on-graphs-with-graph-convolutional-networks-7d2250723780
    This helped:
    https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/extending.html

    """
    def __init__(self, input_features, output_features, device, bias=True):
        super(GraphConvLayer, self).__init__()

        self.input_features = input_features
        self.output_features = output_features
        self.device = device

        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(self.input_features, self.output_features))

        if bias:
            self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(self.output_features))
        else:
            self.register_parameter('bias', None)

        # Not a very smart way to initialize weights
        self.weight.data.uniform_(-0.1, 0.1)
        if bias is not None:
            self.bias.data.uniform_(-0.1, 0.1)

    def forward(self,input, adj):
        # Here, we put in the forward pass:
        # Our forward pass needs to be:
        # D^-1 * (A + 1) * X * weights
        input, adj = input.float(), adj.float()

        Identity = torch.eye( len(adj[0]), device = self.device)
        A_hat = adj + Identity

        D = torch.sum(A_hat, dim=0)
        len_D = len(D)
        zero = torch.zeros(len_D,len_D, device = self.device)
        mask = torch.diag(torch.ones_like(D, device = self.device))
        D = mask*torch.diag(D) + (1. - mask)*zero

        D_inv = torch.inverse(D)
        out = torch.mm(input, self.weight)
        out = torch.spmm(A_hat,out)
        out = torch.spmm(D_inv, out)

        if self.bias is not None:
            return out + self.bias
        else:
            return out

        return out

    def extra_repr(self):
        # (Optional)Set the extra information about this module. You can test
        # it by printing an object of this class.
        return 'node_features={}, length of weights={}, bias={}'.format(
            self.node_features, self.input_features, self.bias is not None
        )
```

Specifically, in the forward pass I am doing a selection of transformations that are described in the towardsdatascience link in the class. Is there something here that is causing this large slow-down? It seems to me that the tensors are all being initialised on the GPU.

Secondly, as all my graphs are different sizes I am being forced into using a batch size of 1. In my training loop I have this:

```
        for batch in tqdm(train_loader):
            opt.zero_grad()
            adjacency, features, _, nodes = batch
            adjacency = adjacency.to(device)
            features = features.to(device)
            nodes = nodes.to(device)

            output = model(features[0], adjacency[0])

            loss = F.nll_loss(output, nodes[0])
            loss.backward()
            opt.step()
```

This means (as I interpret it) that every single piece of data is being moved to the GPU individually, every loop. This seems like an obvious cause of inefficiency. Is there a way to move all the data into GPU memory at once, outside the training loop, allowing me to remove the `adjacency = adjacency.to(device)` lines?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is almost guaranteed to be bound by the memory movement to the GPU, especially since you mention your singular batches.

The only ways that may help you speed up the current implementation might be to look into [memory maps](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#memory-pinning), which we are not able to see whether or not you are already using them based on the provided code.

Other than that, even with differently sized adjacency matrix, [padding](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence) might be a valid strategy, if you manage to sort your batches by somewhat equal sizes.

Your `forward()` function is also clearly not optimized and might be able to deliver some sort of speedup, but I would expect optimization towards better batching to be of much greater improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have been able to implement the memory map in the link you provided, and are able to 'pin' my data. However, this has not considerably improved my performance. I have been trying to avoid using padding - instead relying on the convolutional layers. I may try explore this soon though. Without some way to make all the inputs the same size it seems I may not be able to get the speed increases I am looking for. I may be able to settle though with current CPU performance. Thanks again